# Method for mapping Longitude and Latitude to MapTile Coordinates using << operator

Tags: c#, operators, bit-shift

So I am looking at a program that downloads map tiles. From [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Mathematics) I have got a method for c# for getting a tiles grid coordinates from longitude and latitude points that looks like this:

```
public PointF WorldToTilePos(double lon, double lat, int zoom)
{
    PointF p = new PointF();
    p.X = (float)((lon + 180.0) / 360.0 * (1 << zoom));
    p.Y = (float)((1.0 - Math.Log(Math.Tan(lat * Math.PI / 180.0) + 
        1.0 / Math.Cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0)) / Math.PI) / 2.0 * (1 << zoom));

    return p;
}
```

on the same site it states that the mathematics for working this out are:
[image]

where z = zoom.

Now my question is what does the << operator do and what does (1 << zoom) mean. Because as far as I can see the c# method is incorrect and (1 << zoom) should be replaced with `Math.Pow(2,zoom);` in x and `Math.Pow(2,zoom-1)` for y.

Comment: it's a left-shift operator - check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(1 << (zoom-1))` for `y`?

Comment: This is my question from looking at the mathematics I'm starting to question the method shown on the wiki. Also the fact I am getting some strange results from the method over 1000s of locations

Comment: @PeterMmm The `/ 2` in the code gives the `-1`.

Comment: @peterMmm `zoom=0` for `(1 << (zoom-1))` compared to `Math.Pow(2,zoom - 1)` gives some strange results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a left shift operator. It is shifting the bits in the number `1` to the left by `zoom` number of places.

In the context of this `1 << zoom`, it is basically creating a power of 2.

If zoom equals `3`, then its doing a `2^3`:

```
0000 0001 = 1
After executing 1 << zoom (3)
0000 1000 = 8
```

As you pointed out, you could replace it with `Math.Pow`, however, bit operations are much, much faster. `Math.Pow` has to deal with the problem in its general case, dealing with fractional powers and other issues. Bit operations are natural CPU operations, that execute in a single CPU cycle.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is a bit-shifting operator.

Consider the binary number 00001110 (decimal 14). When it's bit-shifted to the left by 1, it becomes 00011100 (decimal 28). The latter, when bit-shifted to the right by 1, becomes 00001110 (decimal 14) again.

Typically, bit-shifting an integer by 1 causes a multiplication by 2 (when shifting to the left) or an integer division by 2 (when shifting to the right).

Bit-shifting by 2 (that is, bit-shifting by 1, two times) causes a multiplication by 2*2 or an integer division by 2*2.

In the general case, bit-shifting a number by N causes multiplication or division by 2^N.

Answer (score -1):

It bitshifts the one to the left zoom number of times. This is effectively the same thing as raising 2 to the zoom power.

For y, it achieves the z-1 by dividing by two

Comment: `This is effectively the same thing as raising it to the zoom power.`  No, it's not.  1 to the Nth power is 1.

Comment: @Servy numbers are represented as binary 2-complement.

Comment: @PeterMmm Yes, they are.  That doesn't change the fact that this answer is currently wrong.  Nor is the way that the number is stored actually relevant in determining what this operator does.  (I could store the number as a 1-compliment and still implement the `<<` operator with the same semantics.)

Comment: `That doesn't change the fact that this answer is currently wrong.` that was my first thought.

Comment: how would I acheive `2^z-1` using a bitshift operator?

Comment: @Servy, My answer was unclear. I meant that bitshifting 1 to the left was the same as raising 2 to the zoom power as referenced in the question

Comment: @user1, dividing by 2 reduces the power it is being raised to by one